# How do I make a startup macro to show current slide number automatically?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am stil new to macros and I can't make it load automatically on startup. So, please walk me through it from the beginning.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: See [How to auto execute a macro when opening a Powerpoint presentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306007/how-to-auto-execute-a-macro-when-opening-a-powerpoint-presentation). This should give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerPoint 2007 and onward, there's a clever trick (worked out by John Wilson, I'm pretty sure).  By adding RibbonX code that includes a callback, you can get code to run when a PPTM or PPSM opens.  Since PPTX/PPSX files cannot contain code, they won't work, of course.

John explains the magic here:
http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/PowerPoint_Auto_Open_Code.html

Comment: No that is not what I am looking for.
I used auto_open sub for a simple code.
But I am still stuck with how to make the number of currently displayed slide appear somewhere onscreen.

Comment: You asked for a way to make a macro load automatically on startup.  If you want something else, consider asking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this video explains it to you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0fjrcMp8vA
using Insert->Slide Number in a Text Box.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer! Generally you'll want to summarize these kinds of answers rather than just dumping a link, since links tend to go away over time and ruin your answer.